# HDD Data Recovery

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover harddrive data](https://superuser.com/questions/87188/recover-harddrive-data)

My Laptop was running slow because of the HDD and all of a sudden a got I blue screen and could not restart the computer. I bought a new HDD and mounted on the laptop and now it works fine but the problem is I have a lot of photos, music and documents on the old one I don't wanna lose forever.

Is there any way I can recover the data from the old HDD?

HITACHI: HTS541680J9SA00 80GB

Comment: This type of question has been answered a couple of times here. Try [here](http://superuser.com/questions/87188/recover-harddrive-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options.  The first thing you should do is to get an external USB case that can hold your HDD.  This way you can connect it to your laptop and see if it can read anything.  There is a good chance that you can read it.

The next option is to look at some recovery programs.  I had a similar problem and used one called "Recovery Data for FAT & NTFS".  It recovered most of my data.  You can download it as a free trial and it will show you what it can see from your new HDD.  If you like what you see, you need to buy it in order to pull the data off.