# Recovering a striped volume

Tags: unix, raid, data-recovery, ddrescue

Is it possible to recover a striped volume (6 TB from two 3 TB disks) that has had all it's data removed with sudo rm -rf? Assuming no overwrites. As a last resort (I'm a student with very few resources) would a data recovery service like Kroll Ontrack or Drivesavers be able to do it?

Comment: No, Its not possible.  You can try http://www.piriform.com/blog/2013/2/15/recuva-v145 but due to the way the RAID 0 works its unlikely.

Comment: It won’t be easy –– the fact that you’re using RAID won’t help –– but you have as much of a chance as anybody else who’s done a `rm -rf`.  Look around –– [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/87188/recover-harddrive-data) seems to have some answers that might be good starting points.