# Recovering files from harddrive

Tags: hard-drive

My laptop got broken (by what it seems the graphics card burned) and it is so old that it is not worth fixing it.

I took the harddrive from it and tried to use it as external hard drive with other computer, however I cannot access all the data, ie anything that is inside my user folder (it shows it to be empty). Couldn't find anything to solve it.

Comment: I've used a program called DiskGenius in the past for situations like this.

Comment: Read the "Related" questions, to the right? Like https://superuser.com/questions/87188/recover-harddrive-data?rq=1 Or does the drive work 100% perfectly, and you just don't know what files to copy?

Comment: Drive works, but it just seems that directories are protected and cannot be explored. For example, if I type in in the explorer search name of file that is inside my user directory, I would see it in the search result. However, if I try to open the file directory, I get an error: Access is denied. (if I am not clear enough, I can make explanation using screenshots)

Answer (score 4):

#### I cannot access all the data

You need to take ownership of the files/directories on the hard drive.

The following assumes you are using windows (and should work for versions other than Windows 8).

Note:

- Do **not** take ownership of `C:\`.

  Doing so, could result in Windows 8 becoming very unstable.

---

#### Take Ownership of an Object using TAKEOWN Command

This command will take ownership of the folder or drive, and all files and subfolders in the folder or drive.

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To grant ownership to currently logged on user:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /R /D Y
```

To grant ownership to the administrators group:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /A /R /D Y
```

Examples:

```
takeown /F "F:" /A /R /D Y
takeown /F "F:\Folder" /A /R /D Y
```

---

#### Take Ownership of a Folder or Drive and All Contents using ICALCS Command

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To set any user as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "user name" /T /C
```

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Example:

```
icacls "C:\Windows\Folder" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Source [Take Ownership of a File, Folder, Drive, or Registry Key in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: I recommend using the environment variable `%USERNAME%`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 For what exactly?

Comment: ... `/setowner "user name"`... if the user in question is the one you are logged in as, which it likely is in this scenario.