# Windows Backup got interrupted, how can I find and delete the backup files created during the interrupted session?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, windows-7-backup

I tried to create a backup on my external hard drive, but unfortunately that got interrupted. Before I ran the backup program, the external hard drive had 860 GB free. Now, it says it has 660 GB free. The 200 GB must be the backup files created during the interrupted session, but I can't find the files anywhere, and the Backup and Restore page of control panel doesn't believe there are any backup files on the hard drive. How can I find and delete it to free up 200 GB?

Answer (score 0):

open the external drive in windows explorer--change the folder view to show 'hidden files'--look for file that's about 200GB

Comment: Tried it, but there are no new files or folders about that size.

Comment: plug in external drive--see if recycle bin has content--if so--empty recycle bin

Comment: The Recycle Bin is empty.

Answer (score 0):

#### My computer crashed during a backup

> The temperature of my room caused it to overheat and crash

Run a [Disk Check](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2641432):

> 1. Right click the Start Windows icon.
> 2. In the shortcut menu, click Open Windows Explorer.
> 3. In the navigation pane, click Computer so that your drives appear in the right pane.
> 4. Right-click the drive that you want to check.
> 5. Click Properties.
> 6. Click the Tools tab.
> 7. Click the Check now button.
> 8. In the Check Disk  window, select the Automatically fix file system errors check box.
>
> Note:
>
> If you want to perform a detailed test of the hard drive, you can
>   select the Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors check box. You
>   should do that in the justified suspicion of existing hardware error
>   in any case. But please note that the operation can then take a long
>   time. For a first routine check, we recommend that you do not select
>   this option.
>
> 9. Click Start.
> 10. If the drive that you want to check is currently in use and it is your system drive, you will see a dialog box with a warning message.
>       In this case, click Schedule disk check.
> 11. Exit all open programs, and then restart your computer. The checking will start automatically before next Windows startup and
>       display the results when completed.
> 12. If you are not checking the system drive, you do not have to turn off the computer. However, the selected drive may also be in use. In
>       this case, you receive a message. After you have saved all files and
>       close all open programs, click Force a dismount.
> 13. The checking starts immediately. After it is completed, the results will be displayed.

---

#### I can't find the backup files anywhere

You need to enable the viewing of hidden **and** protected system files:

- Go to Explorer > "Tools" > "Folder options" > "View"
- Select "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"
- Untick "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)"

  [image]
- Browse your backup drive:

  [image]

---

> Windows 7’s backup tool hides its backup sets from casual view (and
>   casual access) via a special permission privacy attribute. This
>   attribute keeps standard file-management tools — such as Windows
>   Explorer — from easily seeing or altering what’s inside the backups.
>
> Here’s an example. Figure 1 shows the Properties box for a Win7 backup
>   folder on a test PC named “NV4K.” As you can see, Windows Explorer
>   can’t see inside the backup folder and reports it as zero length, zero
>   files, zero folders.
>
> [image]

Source [Holy …! My Win7 backup folders are empty!](http://windowssecrets.com/langalist-plus/holy-8230-my-win7-backup-folders-are-empty/)

Comment: I have enabled the viewing of protected and hidden files. However, the only new folder/file to appear on my hard drive is $RECYCLE.BIN. There is nothing that seems like a backup file/folder, or anything else that was newly created.

Comment: @user477049 Are you logged on as an Adminstrator?

Comment: Yes, I am logged onto an account with Administrator privileges.

Comment: How did it get interrupted? Did you click "Stop Backup"? Or did something else happen?

Comment: The temperature of my room caused it to overheat and crash.

Comment: Then I would run run a [Disk Check](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2641432). Answer updated.

Comment: I've run a disk check. It did not find any problems.

Comment: Ok. Try a [Disk Cleanup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/delete-files-using-disk-cleanup#delete-files-using-disk-cleanup=windows-7). If that doesn't work I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Disk Cleanup had nothing to clean. The recycle bin was empty.

Comment: One last idea. Take ownership of the whole external drive - see if any news files/folders are now visible. See my answer [Recovering files from harddrive](http://superuser.com/a/874966) for instructions.

Comment: I've tried it, but there were no new files.

Comment: @user477049 No further ideas at this time :/