# Access Old User Directory on previous (faulty) SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-10, data-recovery, user-accounts

I recently had a problem with the SSD I was using as my OS drive and I had to replace it.

Just out of interest I tried plugging the old SSD in again and I appear to be able to see and read data from it.  The odd thing is that the only directory I cannot see is the one I'm interested in.My old Users directory.  I can see `Users\Default` and `Users\Public` but not `Users\<username>`.

Is this expected behavior or can I reveal it somehow? Is there a way to attempt to detect that might be a damaged bit of disk?  Seems strange that it would be the only one I can't see and the only one probably worth securing somehow, given the scenario.

I've viewed the SSD SMART data using the OCZ suite of tools and all looks completely healthy.

**UPDATE**

After looking at Davids suggested commands I ran the following one:

`icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C`

This went through the entire drive and I saw all the stuff I'm interested in get listed.  However I still cannot view them in the explorer window.

Comment: It looks like you're talking about some version of Windows? Maybe try going into Explorer, and then go into its settings and enable "Show hidden files and folders"? I can't say exactly how to do this as I don't know what version of Windows you're running, but maybe this guide will help?: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/?PageSpeed=noscript

Comment: I always have that setting turned on.  It's Windows 10 btw

Comment: Your replacement drive probably has a different set of SSIDs (the owners of files) because they are from a different install of Windows (I presume). Try to take ownership of the whole old drive (be careful **not** to do this on the new drive). See my answer to another similar question here [Recovering files from harddrive](http://superuser.com/a/874966)

Comment: What was the problem with the SSD which made you to change it? If its data corruption/loss, then your chance to recover the `User data` is very narrow. Try using the tool at: http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/other-recovery-software/SSD-drive-recovery.htm Don't know to what extend it will help.

Comment: I've updated after using Davids commands.