# External hdd wont open

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, data-recovery

My external hdd appears on my computer but won't open. It appears in disk management as well as active and healthy. Is there a way to recover the files in the external hdd?

**EDIT**
So far I have used the following data recovery software with no success:

1. EaseUS recovery software
2. Recuva
3. PC Inspector File Recovery

My machine is on windows.

Comment: There are plenty of data recovery tools (both free and paid) that can get your data back (as long as nothing too crazy has been done to the drive like a reformat), but before you go that far, `wont open` in what way? As in you just don't see a drive letter or you get a specific error when you try to open the drive? If it's the former, then you should be able to right click and 'Assign/Change Drive Letter...' on the disk ..?

Comment: Should be a way to see some detailed logfiles or errors on windows, isn't there? Something like `/var/log/syslog` in linux. And even a quick format doesn't really overwrite much data, I'd try [`testdisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and `photorec` first, they're free and available for Windows/Linux/Mac/DOS (really)/FreeBSD/SunOS

Comment: Its an external drive that when double clicking on it windows explorer crashes. On multiple different laptops

Comment: Instructions for using TestDisk and PhotoRec: http://superuser.com/questions/87188/recover-harddrive-data/994605#994605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard disk is most probably dead. I used data recovery software to get the data from it and then just threw it away. I do not to state which software I used as it is a paid for software and not free, and I do not wish to promote a specific software.