# Seagate Paragon external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive

I did some very wrong today. I was going to format my new seagate Paragon external hard drive to NFTS to Mac. So I went to Tools -> Disk utilities and I choose the external drive, and went up to Erase, and picked Mac OS extended, but it erased all.

But now my iMac can't find the external hard drive, and I installed the driver correctly, but it stand "Not Active". So how can I get it active again?

Comment: Your at data recovery at this point.....https://superuser.com/questions/87188/recover-harddrive-data